# Running Sonar Code Analysis from Eclipse Instance

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

We use Jenkins for both building application and running sonar analysis through maven on the code.

I am able create a local server, and run sonarqube analysis using sonar runner.

I was able to connect my  eclipse instance to the company sonarqube runner and get the issues from existing analysis on eclipse. But while running 'Analyse' from eclipse, it fails.

It returns,
*You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.sources*

While I looked into the process, I found that, a temporary sonar-runner is downloaded in the temp folder and a sonar-project.properties is created and the analysis is run using that. This property file does not have the sonar.sources defined inside it. Since this property file is not in my control, How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Just a suggestion: Is maven an option for you? Works fine from inside eclipse and can be used to run an analysis.

Comment: If you can let me know how to go about that..

Comment: Well, you need your project to be a maven project, add some stuff (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven) for SonarQube and then simply run the `sonar:sonar` goal.

Comment: Surely I'll try this too.. But they may not allow changing of project facet though.

Comment: Well, maven is a big step, obviously, just for SonarQube it would be overkill. On the other hand, it has many advantages on it's own (if you are not yet using Gradle, of course).

Comment: In Jenkins, we analyze using the maven sonar:sonar goal only, I faced issue while running analyze on the project from eclipse

Comment: In this case, I'm sorry that I can't help, never tried that for long, I simply tend to integrate it in maven and go with it.

Answer (score 1):

The `sonar-project.properties` config file must be in the root of your eclispe project. And it should looks like this:

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=nutch-key
sonar.projectName=nutch-prj
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
# Path to the parent source code directory.
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on   Windows.
# Since SonarQube 4.2, this property is optional. If not set, SonarQube starts looking for source code
# from the directory containing the sonar-project.properties file.
sonar.sources=src
# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
# Additional parameters
sonar.my.property=value
```

Comment: I have tried this..If I want to run a local server sonar analysis, I'll be doing the one you suggested. My project is connected to the company sonarqube, and i want to run analysis on the project which will update both the server and local results..

Comment: In Eclipse, Go to Window > Preferences > SonarQube > Servers to setup your company's sonar. Then right click your project , Configure -> Associate with SonarQube.

Comment: I have done all that, if you could read my description, I face problem while running analyze, it creates temp sonar-runner instance and sonar properties file and tries running it, which fails because there is no sonar.sources present in that file

Answer (score 0):

SQ Eclipse plugin will use the configured Eclipse (JDT) source folders and pass them to sonar.sources. Check that you have some source folders configured (Right click on project -> Properties -> Java build path).

Comment: Yes, the source folders are configured in the Java build path. Still the plugin is not able to pass them to sonar.sources